# What is the recommended sqlite nuget package for uwp applications?

Tags: sqlite, uwp

What is the recommended SQLite nugget package for uwp applications? (There are so many) Any input would be appreciated? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite.net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL) is a popular one, and is the one I've been using. It is SQLite wrapper that uses linq to query and manipulate the database. You will also need to download the SQLite native binaries SDK (https://sqlite.org/download.html - universal windows platform visx) and reference it from your project.